# Adding a condtion to remove a hook only in my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a Wordpress plugin that creates users, and I want to call
`remove_action(user_register, 'function')` only when my plugin creates a user. Not when a user is created normally. What condition would i check for to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just above your function to create user you can simply call the remove action on what you would like to remove, create the user, then add the action back again for the rest of the site to work as usual. It would become something like this:

```
function my_create_user_function(){
    remove_action('user_register', 'function');
    // do stuff
    wp_insert_user($user_data);
    // do stuff
    add_action('user_register', 'function');
}
```